Field [inputValue] is unexpected in the struct
I edited a script that's been in place a running fine for a long time.  I just added a single device.
Upon saving I get the error Field [inputValue] is unexpected in the struct.
I haven't changed anything in the structure of the script, I literally just adding one device to a list of devices.
Has something changed in the land of Home Scripting?  The docs still show InputValue as being correct.
Is anyone else having this issue?
